# Time-changed Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion and let $\tau_{-1}= \inf \{ t \geq 0: B_t(\omega) = -1\}$.

By the Continuous Time Stopping Theorem we know that 
\begin{align}
Z_t = B_{t \wedge \tau_{-1}}
\end{align}
is a martingale. Now, we define a time-change $X_t(\omega) = Z_{\frac{t}{1-t}}(\omega)$ for $0 \leq t <1$, where $X_t$ is a martingale as well, with almost sure convergence
\begin{align}
P\big(\lim_{t \to 1} X_t = -1\big)=1.
\end{align}
We extend the defintion by $X_t = -1$ for $t \geq 1$.

I want to show that $X_t$ is not a martingale anymore, but a local martingale which can be localized by the localizing sequence $\tau_k(\omega) = \inf \{ t \geq 0: X_t(\omega) = k\}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have problems showing X is not a martingale?

Comment: Yep, and to show that $X$ is a local martingale.

Comment: Ìf you have no idea to show that $X$ is not a martingale then the rest of the question is rather moot, I would say... Anyway, can you compare $E(X_0)$ and $E(X_1)$?